# Can I proxy an existing Visual Studio LanguageService?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, plugins, system.reflection

I would like to extend Visual Studio's parsing of C++ with additional information computed by a custom extension I am writing. In order to save me the hassle of writing a complete `IScanner` for my `LanguageService`, I thought I would query for the `LanguageService` responsible for scanning C++, and simply proxy to it.

My searches so far only pointed me to complete `LanguageService` reimplementations using *eg.* ANTLR or custom scanners. I attempted to use `System.Reflection` from my Visual Studio addon, but it didn't seem to show me any classes except mine.

So, any idea how I can retrieve a `LanguageService` instance that understands C++?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to proxy C++ LanguageService (or any other lagnguage service), as it is not architected to have the extensibility points. So you could only re-implement it from scratch (which would be a really hard task). The purpose of a language service in Visual Studio is to provide language-specific support for editing source code in the IDE. Are you sure you need language service? Waht kind of extension do you work on?

As for getting Visual Studio services you could have a look at this good article "[LearnVSXNow! #26 - Services — with no-code service initialization](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/07/23/LearnVSXNowPart26.aspx)"